# How to get the text of the option

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I parsed the html content and get the

```
datatag = '<select name="cyfbh" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option>\n<option selected="selected" value="440615000101">440615000101-passenger car</option>\n<option value="440615000102">440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle</option></select>'
```

How to extract `"440615000101-passenger car"` and `"440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle"` from the above tag? How to get the text of the option?

I tried the below option, but I am getting the complete option, not the value.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(datatag,'lxml')
text_area = soup.find('option') # locate textarea tag
```

Comment: `find` and `find_all` always return tag object. You have to use `.text` to get text - `find('option').text`

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use `find_all` to get all `<option>`

And then you have to use `for`-loop to get option one-by-one and use `.text` to get only text from this option.

You can also use `if` to skip empty text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

datatag = '''<select name="cyfbh" style="width:100%">
<option value=""></option>\n
<option selected="selected" value="440615000101">440615000101-passenger car</option>\n
<option value="440615000102">440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle</option>
</select>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(datatag, 'lxml')

all_options = soup.find_all('option')

for option in all_options:
    if option.text: # skip empty options
        print('    text:', option.text)
        print('   value:', option['value']) # without defaul value
        #print('   value:', option.get('value')) # default value `None`
        #print('   value:', option.get('value', 'FooBar')) # default value 'FooBar'
        print('selected:', option.get('selected'))
```

or shorter to create list with all text

```
all_options = soup.find_all('option')

text = [option.text for option in all_options if option.text]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
# find all option tags
res = soup.find_all('option')

# return the tag value for each of those options
options = [x.text for x in res]
```

Which yields this in `options`:

```
['', '440615000101-passenger car', '440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle']
```

To exclude any empty string from `options`, simply try:

```
no_empties = [x for x in options if len(x) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a="""
<select name="cyfbh" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option>\n<option selected="selected" value="440615000101">440615000101-passenger car</option>\n<option value="440615000102">440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle</option></select>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(a)
b = soup.select("option")
print b[1].text
print b[2].text
```

Output:

```
440615000101-passenger car
440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
from lxml import etree
datatag = '<select name="cyfbh" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option>\n<option selected="selected" value="440615000101">440615000101-passenger car</option>\n<option value="440615000102">440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle</option></select>'
datatag = etree.HTML(datatag)
values = datatag.xpath("//option[@value!='']/text()")
```

This way you would end up with a list containing the values you are looking for.